# Eclipse suddenly shows lots of "List is a raw type" warnings

Tags: eclipse, warnings

I've been working on JFreeChart in Eclipse for some time. Everything was going great and there were no warnings or errors last time I worked on it. The entire copy is local to my computer.

I opened the project tonight and suddenly there are hundreds of warnings - almost all of them because the project uses `List` without providing parameters. It says: `List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized`

These warnings never showed up before and I don't remember changing anything in the last week that could have affected it.

Does anyone have any ideas of what might have caused this and how to turn them all off at once?

Thanks[image: List is a raw type]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is controlled by 'Java / Compiler / Errors/Warnings / Generic types / Usage of raw type' in the Preferences (could be Project Specific or Global).

Comment: JFreeChart is written to work with JDK 1.4 which does not have generics (they came in 1.5) so you'll get a lot of these warnings when working with the JFreeChart source code.  As @greg-449 said, you can turn off these warnings in the Eclipse preferences.